# Chameleons of Three Colors puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, puzzle, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the solution to the below puzzle

> There are 13 Red, 15 Green, and 17 Blue Chameleons at some point of
>   time. Whenever two Chameleons of the different colors meet both of
>   them change their color to the third color. Is it ever possible for
>   all Chameleons to become of the same color?

I am able to figure out "manually step by step" that it is not possible to get all in one color. 
However I don't understand the more formal solution using the modulo, for example Solution 1 [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Chameleons.shtml). 


I realize that after every change the differennce between the second and first terms is -3, 0 or 3.

What are the vectors (2,2,2) representing?

I don't understand the final statement there:

`We see that, with the initial vector (1, 0, 2) modulo 3, the only possible` `combinations of colors on the island are (1, 0, 2), (0, 2, 1), and (2, 1, 0),` `and these occur cyclically with period 3.`

Can anybody explain in simple way this solution to the problem?

Comment: Any number that is a multiple of three we say is equivalent to zero mod3.  Any number that is one more than a multiple of three we say is equivalent to one mod3.  Similarly for numbers two more than a multiple of three.  The initial state can be referred to mod3 as $(1,0,2)$ since $13,15,17$ are equivalent to $1,0,$ and $2$mod3 respectively.  The linked solution points out that regardless which two chameleons meet, the vector will always have one of each of $0,1,2$ in some order.

Comment: *Remark.*  The chameleon puzzle has been discussed on this site before. See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145725) or [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/559201). The current asks the users to explain a certain proof, so it isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to show that:

$$(17,15,13)+a(-1,-1,2)+b(-1,2,-1)+c(2,-1,-1)$$
is never $(45,0,0), (0,45,0),$ or $(0,0,45)$ for $a,b,c$ integers.

But since $(2,-1,-1)=(-1)(-1,2,-1)+(-1)(2,-1,-1)$, you can eliminate the third term and ask to find $a,b,$ so that we only need to show that:

$$(17,15,13)+a(-1,-1,2)+b(-1,2,-1)$$

can never be $(45,0,0), (0,45,0),$ or $(0,0,45)$ when $a,b$ are integers.

If we have such $a,b$, then $a+b\equiv 17\pmod {45}, 2b-a\equiv -15\pmod{45}$ and thus $3b\equiv 2\pmod{45}$, which is impossible.

---

Another way to state this is:

> If $(x,y,z)+a(-1,-1,2)+b(-1,2,-1)+c(2,-1,-1) = (x',y',z')$ then $x-y\equiv x'-y'\pmod{3}$ and $y-z\equiv y'-z'\pmod{3}$.

So if $(x',y',z')=(45,0,0),(0,45,0)$ or $(0.0,45)$ then $x-y\equiv 0\pmod 3$. But $17-15\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

This also means you can't get to $(15,15,15)$ since again it would mean $x-y\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Comment: Also, you can get from $(15, 15, 15)$ to  $(45,0,0)$ or any permutation, by matching the $30$ chameleons of any two colors. Interestingly, for two triplets $a$ and $b$, the relation $a \,\mathbf{R} \, b$ defined as "$a$ can be reached from $b$ by pairing chameleons" is an equivalence relation.

Comment: As you have shown, $(17,15,13)$ is not in the same equivalence class as $(45,0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can see that

Red chameleons mod 3 = 13 mod 3 = 1

Green chameleons mod 3 = 15 mod 3 = 0

Blue chameleons mod 3 = 17 mod 3 = 2

Then, you take all possible cases

If a red chameleon meets a green chameleon, it becomes (0 2 1), which is subtract 1 modulo 3 from the first two components and add 2 modulo 3 on the third component.

If a red chameleon meets a blue chameleon ...

If a green chameleon meets a blue chameleon...

Now we suppose that we are in the state (0, 2, 1)

If a red chameleon meets a green chameleon...

and so on

Comment: @ Momo what is the interpretation of this equation $(1, 0, 2) + (2, 2, 2) = (0, 2, 1)  (mod 3)$ and especially what the (2,2,2) means?

Comment: subtracting one from one component is the same to adding 2 (modulo 3). So (-1, -1, 2) = (2, 2, 2) mod 3. This is the case when a red and a blue chameleon meet. The other cases are (-1, 2, -1) and (2, -1, -1), but as you see, they are all congruent to (2,2,2) modulo 3

Comment: So the interpretation is 1+2=0 (mod 3), 0+2=2(mod 3) and 2+2=1(mod 3)

Comment: In other words, if you count chameleons of each color (Red, Green, Blue) modulo 3, after the first two chameleons meet, you will get (0, 2, 1) regardless of what colors meet.

Comment: @ Momo Excuse my ignorance, I don't understand the $(-1, -1, 2) = (2, 2, 2) mod 3$

Comment: By the [quotient-reminder theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724032/quotient-remainder-theorem-proving):

$a=qb+r$ with $0≤r<|b|$

So $-1 = 3(-1)+2$, with $0\le 2<3$

So $-1\equiv 2\ \ (\text{ mod } 3)$